# Null terminator in c++ strings

Tags: c++, string, c++11

Is there any way to work normally with strings that can conatain "\0"? For example:

```
std::string a("abc\0def");
std::cout << a.length();
```

this produces output:

```
3
```

I understand that \0 is used in C to signal the end of an array of chars, but I didn't think it would work like this in c++ as well? I haven't been able to find this explained in detail anywhere.

Comment: ***I didn't think it would work like this in c++ as well?*** The problem is the string literal.

Comment: ... `std::string a("abc\0def", 7);`, in the other words.